# CoordinatorLayout anchor sometimes reposition FAB in fragment

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_remove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_upload"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/navigate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_navigate"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my xml code. My FAB sometimes appears at top left corner & sometimes appears in its prescribed anchor position. I am setting a recycler view in my fragment & setting it up after getting data from server. What should I change to get FAB in its correct position?

Comment: make your CoordinatorLayout  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: @Nilesh tried... not working

Comment: Hey @AshishJohn did you found any solution?